# How can I solve ruby-on-rails migration problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a problem with migration. When I put rake db:migrate into terminal I got an error :

> rake aborted!
> StandardError: Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Active Record release the migration was written for:
> class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]

And When I'm changing into migration file

> class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration

to

> class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]

I'm getting an error:

> rake aborted!
> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
> wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)

How can I solve that ?

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def self.up 
    change_table :pins do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down 
    remove_attachment :pins, :image
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the content of the migration? It seems it's a error inside of it.

Comment: class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :pins do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :pins, :image
  end
end

Comment: Based on your migration column types, I assume you are using the Paperclip gem, since `t.attachment` is not built into ActiveRecord migrations (at least in postgres). Paperclip is deprecated, and they might not offer full support for Rails 7. These [open issues on Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+wrong+number+of+arguments+%28given+3%2C+expected+2%29) have the same errors you are seeing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it's clear what I was expected - how to make migration.